# Enmascarar input text

Tags: javascript, css3

Estimados colegas tengo un input text que quiero al momento de ingresar caracteres me "oculte" el texto por un asterisco o un punto (tipo password)

no ocupo el type password ya que la intencion es que el navegador no me solicite recordar contraseña

no coloco codigo porque no se por donde empezar, queria saber si me dan sus sugerencias

Comment: Colocar el código que has intentado o por lo menos la parte importante de este es necesario para dar una idea a los demas programadores de aquello que has intentado sin exito.

Answer (score 0):

No creo que sea recomendable usar un input de tipo text en vez de un input de tipo password solo porque este luego te muestra un dialogo de confirmación para guardar o no una contraseña.

Después de todo el dialogo simplemente se puede cerrar si no quieres guardar una contraseña y listo, sin embargo... si deseas hacer esta implementacion con input de tipo text, estuve pensando en lo siguiente:

```js
window.onload = ()=>{

 let container = document.getElementById("container");
 let passwordField = document.getElementById("password_field");
 let fieldLabel = document.getElementById("fieldLabel");

 password_field.addEventListener("keyup", ()=>{

  let passwordContent = passwordField.value.split("");
  fieldLabel.textContent = "";

  passwordContent.forEach(()=>{

   fieldLabel.textContent += "*";

  });

  if(passwordContent.length >= 24){

   container.style.width = "auto";

  }else{

   container.style.width = 200 + "px";

  }

 });
 
}
```

```css
*{

 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 overflow: hidden;

}

.container{

 display: inline-block; 
 border: 1px solid blue; 
 color: #000000; 
 min-width: 200px;
 padding: 0px 10px;
}

.container:hover{

 border: 2px solid blue;

}

.password_field{

 display: inline; 
 padding: 10px 0px; 
 text-indent: -2000px; 
 outline: none; 
 border: none; 
 width: 10px;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Ejemplo</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div id = "container" class = "container">

    <label for= "password_field" id = "fieldLabel" class = "fieldLabel"></label>
    <input type = "text" id="password_field" name="password_field" 
    class = "password_field" maxlength="32">

    </input>

  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

No se si te sirve, pero mas o menos eso es lo que yo haría para hacer lo que tu necesitas, en este caso al input de tipo text le coloque un limite de 32 caracteres (aunque perfectamente puedes quitar este limite quitando la etiqueta maxlength), el funcionamiento de este input es el siguiente:

En css al inicio nos aseguramos de que el contenedor principal del input tenga un width con un valor diferente de auto, así el input no será super pequeño al iniciar la pagina, tambien al input de tipo text, le asignamos un text-indent de -2000px, como sabras, esta propiedad es la identacion que tendrá el input, y si colocamos una identación negativa (Que como vemos se puede), el resultado es que el texto no se verá en el input, tambien al ser un valor negativo tan grande, nos aseguramos de de que no sea posible ver o robar el contenido del input de manera tan sencilla.

Esta propiedad de css en especial, como ves es muy importante para realizar este input, también le he quitado los bordes y el outline al clickear por defecto que tiene este input, ya que si no lo quitamos no obtendremos el resultado que queremos (Veremos separaciones entre los limites del texto completo y el input).

Por ultimo le doy al contenedor principal un borde, así se vera el borde del input de manera correcta y le doy un padding a este input arriba y abajo, pero no a los lados, así se vera mejor.

En javascript extraemos cada uno de estos elementos: el contenedor, el input tipo texto y el label del input tipo texto.

Este label será el texto que si se puede ver (El texto censurado con asteriscos o cualquier otro valor que sea usado para censurar), y a diferencia del input de tipo texto, este no tiene identación.

luego añadimos un eventListener de tipo keyup al input de tipo texto, es decir que cuando una tecla sea soltada se ejecutara esta función, la cual hará lo siguiente:

Obtiene cada una de las "letras" que hay actualmente como valor en el input de tipo texto, estas serán separadas en un arreglo de letras.

Al label del input de tipo texto reseteamos el contenido que tiene y luego recorremos cada una de las letras que habíamos obtenido del input tipo texto, y por cada letra que el ciclo encuentre, le añadira un "*" al label del input de tipo texto.

Esto da como resultado el simular que se esta escribiendo correctamente en el input los caracteres censurados cuando nosotros presionamos alguna tecla imprimible.

por ultimo, para hacer "adaptable" el input comprobamos mas abajo con una condición si la cantidad de caracteres es un numero u otro, en nuestro caso, si el usuario ha introducido 24 caracteres o mas, le cambiaremos el estilo del width de nuestro input a "auto", esto adaptara automáticamente el tamaño del contenedor del input, en caso de que la condición sea falsa, volvemos asignarle al contenedor un ancho fijo.

**¡ACLARACIÓN!**: No recomendaría que usaras para nada esta solución en un proyecto real, sin embargo, tener en cuenta que el contenido valioso del input no se pierde, mantiene su contenido oculto y seguro, lo unico es que ya no es visible ni seleccionable, por lo que si necesitas enviar algún dato atravez de este input extraño podrias hacerlo con total seguridad, ya que los verdaderos datos estan guardados en el atributo value del tipo input text.